# Dot product for arbitrary shaped NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Given two `numpy.ndarray` objects, `A` and `B`, of arbitrary shapes, I'd like to compute an `numpy.ndarray` `C` with the property that `C[i] == np.dot(A[i], B[i])` for all `i`. How can I do this?

Example 1: `A.shape==(2,3,4)` and `B.shape==(2,4,5)`, then we should have `C.shape==(2,3,5)`.

Example 2: `A.shape==(2,3,4)` and `B.shape==(2,4)`, then we should have `C.shape==(2,3)`.

Comment: So the shapes of `A` and `B` are not completely arbitrary.  They are required to have compatible shapes at each `i`.  Namely, `A.shape[0] == B.shape[0]` must be `True`

Comment: `einsum('ijk,ik...->ij...',A,B)` handles your 2 cases.  It just limits `A` to be 3d, `B` can be 2,3,etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a generic solution to cover all kinds of cases / arbitrary shapes using some `reshaping` and [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). `einsum` helps here as we need alignment along the first axis and reduction along the last axes of the input arrays. The implementation would look something like this -

```
def dotprod_axis0(A,B):
    N,nA,nB = A.shape[0], A.shape[-1], B.shape[1]
    Ar = A.reshape(N,-1,nA)
    Br = B.reshape(N,nB,-1)
    return np.squeeze(np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',Ar,Br))
```

### Cases

**I. A : 2D, B : 2D**

```
In [119]: # Inputs
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,4))
     ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(3,4))
     ...: 

In [120]: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
     ...:     print np.dot(A[i], B[i])
     ...:     
33
86
48

In [121]: dotprod_axis0(A,B)
Out[121]: array([33, 86, 48])
```

**II. A : 3D, B : 3D**

```
In [122]: # Inputs
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,4))
     ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,4,5))
     ...: 

In [123]: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
     ...:     print np.dot(A[i], B[i])
     ...:     
[[ 74  70  53 118  43]
 [ 47  43  29  95  30]
 [ 41  37  26  23  15]]
[[ 50  86  33  35  82]
 [ 78 126  40 124 140]
 [ 67  88  35  47  83]]

In [124]: dotprod_axis0(A,B)
Out[124]: 
array([[[ 74,  70,  53, 118,  43],
        [ 47,  43,  29,  95,  30],
        [ 41,  37,  26,  23,  15]],

       [[ 50,  86,  33,  35,  82],
        [ 78, 126,  40, 124, 140],
        [ 67,  88,  35,  47,  83]]])
```

**III. A : 3D, B : 2D**

```
In [125]: # Inputs
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,4))
     ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,4))
     ...: 

In [126]: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
     ...:     print np.dot(A[i], B[i])
     ...:     
[ 87 105  53]
[152 135 120]

In [127]: dotprod_axis0(A,B)
Out[127]: 
array([[ 87, 105,  53],
       [152, 135, 120]])
```

**IV. A : 2D, B : 3D**

```
In [128]: # Inputs
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,4))
     ...: B = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,4,5))
     ...: 

In [129]: for i in range(A.shape[0]):
     ...:     print np.dot(A[i], B[i])
     ...:     
[76 93 31 75 16]
[ 33  98  49 117 111]

In [130]: dotprod_axis0(A,B)
Out[130]: 
array([[ 76,  93,  31,  75,  16],
       [ 33,  98,  49, 117, 111]])
```

Comment: In general, np.dot(x,y) can be well-defined even when len(x.shape)>2 and even when len(x.shape)!=len(y.shape). In practice I can probably just if/else based on A and B's shape for the few cases I currently care about but was hoping not to do that.

Comment: @dshin Yes! Some reshaping might help.

Comment: @dshin Check out the edited code to cover all cases!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want ordinary matrix multiplication for `dot` (not, say, matrix-vector or the weird crap `dot` does for higher dimensions), then sufficiently recent NumPy versions (1.10+) let you do

```
C = numpy.matmul(A, B)
```

and sufficiently recent Python versions (3.5+) let you write that as

```
C = A @ B
```

assuming your NumPy is also sufficiently recent.

Comment: I added a couple examples to the OP, one of which has matrix-vector.